# SAS macro variables: ampersands do not seem to resolve properly in &&var&i

Tags: macros, sas

I am stuck writing a piece of code that features macro variables of the form &&var&i. Let me give a small example:

```
%macro test;
%let i=1;
%let name1=Tom;
%put &&name&i;
%mend;
%test;
```

This gives a warning: "Apparent symbolic reference NAME not resolved."
I thought the %put statement should resolve to

1st step: &name1 (&&-->& and &i-->1)

2nd step: Tom

It seems that in the first step already, SAS searches for the macro variable &name, although there are two ampersands in front of it.

This is the SAS log, with symbolgen enabled.

```
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference NAME not resolved. 
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable I resolves to 1 
&&name1
```

Am I missing something or are there SAS settings that I should check? Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's very odd. Can you turn on options symbolgen, run your sample code, and add the log to your question?

Comment: @Quentin: I added the relevant part of the log

Comment: I'm flummoxed. If you batch submit or start a new SAS session and submit, does you get the same problem?

Comment: @Quentin Thanks for your suggestion. I now get the correct result. (Strange, because I had already tried it in a new session before, then without result.)
Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the session seems to have solved the problem for you as Quentin commented.

Other options you can try if the same problem persists is turning on `symbolgen` option and add dot to resolve the macro variable names `%put &&name&i..;`